# How to get name of TabLayout from string file (getResources) android

Tags: android

I am a new application developer.
I'm trying to get a name TabLayout from a string file. I need to get the name of the Students table and teacher table from the string file.
sorry to ask the question again, but I tried to work on our previous posts and didn't work with me.

this is my code

```
public class FregmantPageAdapter  extends FragmentPagerAdapter {



    public FregmantPageAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (position==0)
return new Table1();

        else
            return new table2();

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        switch (position){
           case 0: return "Students";
             case 1:return "teacher";
       default:return null;


        }


    }

}
```

Comment: why do you need to add get the string from the String file?

Comment: Application language control @GkMohammadEmon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get String from strings.xml you can use
`getString(R.string.string_name)`.

In your case you need a context to use getString(resId).Change your code like this.

```
private Context context;
public FregmantPageAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm,Context context) {
        super(fm);
        this->context = context;

    }
```

Pass your activity `context` via this constructor then you can use `context.getString(resId)`.

Comment: I can't use it the problem : 'getString(android.content.ContentResolver, java.lang.String)' in 'android.provider.Settings.System' cannot be applied to '(int)'